# Text Positioning in Masonry Cards with Html and CSS

Tags: html, css, masonry

For days I've been trying to find a way to make the headlines and texts of the individual Masonry cards occupy certain positions without affecting the other cards. I almost had a solution in the meantime, but it destroyed the view in other devices. Quite frustrating although the solution is certainly very simple.

I want the Text of the Green Cards in the same position like the Text of the other Cards.
[image: Screenshot of the Masonry]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  min-height: 100vh;

}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,         minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  margin: 40px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 35px;

}

.container .box {
  background: #333;
  padding: 90px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: radial-gradient(#f9d423, #f83600);
  font-family: "bergen mono";
  font-size: 2.1vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

h6 {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: "bergen mono";
}

.container .box:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}

.container .box img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container .box:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 1;
  background: radial-gradient(#2bffc3, #72afd3);
  padding-top: 3vh
}

.container .box:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background: radial-gradient(#c4ff29, #89d294);
}

.container .box:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background: radial-gradient(#c4ff29, #89d294);
}

.container .box:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 1;
  background: radial-gradient(#2bffc3, #72afd3);
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50%, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
  }
  .container .box {
    grid-column: unset !important;
    grid-row: unset !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50%, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
  }
  .container .box {
    grid-column: unset !important;
    grid-row: unset !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2377/2377010.svg" alt="">
      <h6 >Überschrift</h6>
      <p>Wash hands with soap and water after touching animals and animal products.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <h6 >Überschrift</h6>
      <p>When coughing and sneezing cover mouth and nose with flexed elbow or tissue.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <h6 >Überschrift</h6>
      <p>Avoid travelling if you have a fever or cough.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <h6 >Überschrift</h6>
      <p>If you have a fever, cough and difficulty breathing, seek medical care early.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <h6 >Überschrift</h6>
      <p>If you are coughing or sneezing, wear musk and must know how to use it and dispose it properly.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <h6 >Überschrift</h6>
      <p>Eat only well cooked food.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <h6 >Überschrift</h6>
      <p>Avoid close contact with animals that are sick.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add the rule margin to the content to automatically center the text, since you are in a flex container.

```
.content {
 margin: auto 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Zhx.jpg)

Comment: this will be too easy, its not working.

Comment: you want all the texts in the middle of their box no? I added a screen of the result

Comment: it works great now, i made a mistake yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a selector that targets only the first box and sets a specific padding. Remove the padding-top so you have uniform white space.

```
.container .box:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 1;
  background: radial-gradient(#2bffc3, #72afd3);
  padding-top: 3vh
}
```

The img-tag in the first element is also standing in the way. Is it necessary?

Since img is an inline-element, you could put it in your h6 instead. Mind that an image will act as a character so if you provide a too big image it will push the text line down. Alternatively you could take it out of normal flow by position absolute.

Comment: Thank you, the answer from cesar and yours combined fix the issue.